# Fb share button works only once without reloading the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I'm trying to add several facebook share buttons on the page, but calling the "share" functions, that shares the current material on facebook, works only once at the page, after one click, you have to reload the page for another sharing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="share js-share-btn">Share</button>
<button class="share js-share-btn">Share</button>
<button class="share js-share-btn">Share</button>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.share {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;  
}
```

And JS:

```
$(".js-share-btn").each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fbShare('title','description');
    return false;
  })
});


function fbShare(title, description, image) {
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.shares',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object : {
         'og:url': 'http://dla.dev',
         'og:title': title,
         'og:description': description,
         'og:image': image
        }
      })
    }, function(response){});
  };
}
```

Here is link on codepen: http://codepen.io/jumkarto/pen/YprMbK

If anyone knows the solution of my problem, I would really appreciate you help.

Comment: The SDK is loaded only once, and therefor the fbAsyncInit  event fires only once as well.

Comment: Why is loaded only once? If I load it every click. And it not, how to load it more than once? Actually every click

Comment: Because the code that embeds it is written that way. And loading it more than once is of course not the solution. Load it once, and call FB.ui _after_ initialization, outside of the fbAsyncInit  event.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the very top of **body** :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3"></script>
```

after that place Share Button :

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="[your_page]" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large">
<a target="_blank" 
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your_page];src=sdkpreparse" 
class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Sdílet
</a>
</div>
```

And just call function `FB.XFBML.parse();` dynamicaly instead of reloading the page.

`FB.XFBML.parse();` <-- fixed for me